# How do you find the intersection point of two or more curves generated from differential equations in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have two differential equations in my MATLAB function file and I found out the solution of those using MATLAB. Now my question is, how to use loops and develop logic to find the intersection point?

I realized that the values that we have are discrete values and the function gives us output at particular step (initial the step size was 0.1) so I reduced the step size to 0.0001.
I thought that if the difference between the absolute values of ith element of the both the differential equation is less than certain threshold value (10^-4) then intersection point is that value.

But I am not getting anything.
My code :

```
% Multiple differential equations
clc;
clear all;
close all;
initial_condition = [0,1];
time_span = [0:0.0001:1];

[t,y] = ode45(@ode_oct_4_5,time_span,initial_condition);

plot(t,y(:,1))
hold on 
plot(t,y(:,2))

% Calculating the value of intersection point

%y_ = round(y,4);
y_diff = abs(y(:,1)-y(:,2));
threshold = 1e-4;
intersection = [];
for i = 1:length(y)
    if abs(y(i, 1) - y(i, 2)) < threshold
        intersection = [intersection; y(i, 1)];
    end
end

disp('The intersection of the curves is : ')
disp(intersection)
```

The function file is :

```
function dydt = ode_oct_4_5(t,y)
dydt = zeros(2,1);
dydt(1) = y(2);
dydt(2) = 1000*(1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1);
```

Comment: The intersection point is where the difference is 0. On one side the difference will be negative, on the other it will be positive. So you need to find the point where the difference changes sign. `fzero` does this.